# Azure Cosmos DB (Table API) v/s Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I'm using ADF for reading data from data lake and storing the data to a cosmos db. I'm figuring out whether I should use azure Cosmos DB Table API or SQL API (Core API). How do these two APIs, namely the Azure Cosmos DB (Table API) and Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API), compare in terms of cost and performance?  Can we use SQL queries with where conditions for reading data from Azure Cosmos DB (Table API) & Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API)?

Comment: Table API is really for folks who have already taken a dependency on Azure Storage Tables and needs something more performant/scalable. If this is a net new application, the SQL API's key/value experience is more flexible than Table API, has more modern libraries, and supports SQL querying if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cost and performance, This is entirely dependent on your use case. Are you able to elaborate on what you're trying to do?

You can't use SQL queries for the Table API, but you can use LINQ if you're developing in C#. If you're not, check out the documentation on the ways you can query data in the Table API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-table

Comment: I'm using ADF for reading data from data lake and storing the data to a cosmos db. I'm figuring out whether I should use azure cosmos db table api or sql api in terms of cost and performance.

Comment: Ah ok, as far as I'm aware, there is no sink for Azure Cosmos DB Table API, (there is one for Table Storage, but whether you can use that as a sink and persist it into a Cosmos DB account I'm not sure) so if you need Cosmos DB, use the SQL API. You can then use SQL queries for your data. I'd go for SQL :)

Comment: What are the types of queries you would run?

Comment: Use the SQL API for both cost and performance. SQL API is our Core API wheras Table API is an emulated layer. If this is key/value data then the most efficient you can get it to turn off indexing in Cosmos DB and make /id your partition key, effectively turning SQL API into a key/value store.